# What does "|>" mean in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm reading through some code elixir code on github and I see `|>` being used often. It does not appear in the list of [operation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html) on the documentation site. What does it mean?

i.e.

```
expires_at:    std["expires_in"] |> expires_at,
```

Comment: In IEx you can use `h |>/2` to see its documentation. It works for any binary operator `h ++/2`, `h +/2`, unary operators `h -/1` or regular functions `h is_atom`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is the [pipe operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2). From the linked docs:

> This operator introduces the expression on the left-hand side as the first argument to the function call on the right-hand side.
>
> Examples
>
> iex> `[1, [2], 3] |> List.flatten()`
>
> `[1, 2, 3]`
>
> The example above is the same as calling `List.flatten([1, [2], 3])`.

Answer (score 40):

It gives you ability to avoid bad code like this:

```
orders = Order.get_orders(current_user)
transactions = Transaction.make_transactions(orders)
payments = Payment.make_payments(transactions, true)
```

Same code using pipeline operator:

```
current_user
|> Order.get_orders
|> Transaction.make_transactions
|> Payment.make_payments(true)
```

Look at `Payment.make_payments` function, there is a second parameter `bool_parameter`. The first parameter references the variable that is calling the pipe:

```
def make_payments(transactions, bool_parameter) do
   //function 
end
```

When developing Elixir application keep in mind that important parameters should be at first place, in future it will give you ability to use pipeline operator.

I hate this question when writing non elixir code: what should i name this variable? I waste lots of time on answer.

Comment: unclear why you say the first lines of code are "bad code" - elaborate please. to a new elixir coder they look like normal code.

Comment: Second lines of code are much easier to read i.e. you have same effect with less code/text written :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Stefan's excellent response, you may want to read the section called "Pipeline Operator" of this [blog posting](http://www.theerlangelist.com/2014/01/why-elixir.html) for a better understanding of the use case that the pipeline operator is intended to address in Elixir. The important idea is this:

> The pipeline operator makes it possible to combine various operations
>   without using intermediate variables. . .The code can easily be
>   followed by reading it from top to bottom. We pass the state through
>   various transformations to get the desired result, each transformation
>   returning some modified version of the state.