# Seeking idiomatic, elegant solution to "send+more=money" in Elixir

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, elixir

I came across [Mark Dominus' blog post](http://blog.plover.com/prog/monad-search-2.html) that describes solving the ["SEND+MORE=MONEY" puzzle](http://ohiorc.org/for/math/stella/problems/problem.aspx?id=113) using functional programming techniques (Monads, specifically) in Python.

The puzzle summarized here in case of dead links:

```
    S E N D   | Find each character's *unique* numerical value, such that
+   M O R E   | the addition on the left is valid. There are no leading zeros.
-----------
= M O N E Y
```

I've been looking for a chance to learn some pure functional programming, specifically with Elixir, and this seemed like a very fitting project.

I can implement a cosmetically similar version of Mark Dominus' Python code in Elixir:

```
defmodule Smm do
  def make_set(ls), do: Enum.into(ls, HashSet.new)

  def to_number([]), do: :error
  def to_number(ls), do: Enum.join(ls) |> Integer.parse |> elem(0)

  def remove(hs, ls), do: Set.difference(hs, Enum.into(ls, HashSet.new))

  def let(x, func), do: func.(x)

  def guard(predicate, func) when predicate, do: func.()
  def guard(predicate, func), do: []
end

digits = Smm.make_set(0..9)

Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [0]), fn s ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s]), fn e ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s,e]), fn n ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n]), fn d ->
Smm.let(Smm.to_number([s,e,n,d]), fn w_send ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [0,s,e,n,d]), fn m ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m]), fn o ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m,o]), fn r ->
Smm.let(Smm.to_number([m,o,r,e]), fn w_more ->
Enum.map( Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m,o,r]), fn y ->
Smm.let(Smm.to_number([m,o,n,e,y]), fn w_money ->
Smm.guard(w_send + w_more == w_money, fn ->
[w_send, w_more, w_money] |> Enum.map( &(IO.puts(&1)) )
end)end)end)end)end)end)end)end)end)end)end)end)        # (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
```

But something tells me there's got to be a way around the insanely nested anonymous functions and the subsequent table-flipping; this is why pure functional languages exist, right?

Looking at Mark Dominus' [previous blog post in which he solves the puzzle with Haskell](http://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/monad-search.html), I see he's using a sugary version of Haskell's "bind" operator `>>=` to eliminate the table-flipping urges... But I haven't [learned me a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), so I don't have a strong grasp on the code presented in this blog post.

I'm fairly certain what I'm missing in my Elixir implementation is using the pipe operator, `|>`, which was actually a big draw to the language for me (being very comfortable with Unix pipes, myself). I've tried working in pipes combined with many flavors of `Enum.{map,reduce}`, but I always end up back at square one.

Can anyone offer any advice? Ideally, I'm looking for a more idiomatic functional programming solution to this puzzle in Elixir.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look here: [What is the "|>" symbol's purpose in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755499/what-is-the-symbols-purpose-in-elixir) for an overview of the `|>` operator. But the basic idea is that `a |> f(b, c)` is the same as `f(a, b, c)`. This is pretty useful when you do something like `a |> f(b) |> g(c)` which by the rule above is the same as `g(f(a, b), c)`, but reads much more nicely.

With that said the `|>` operator (called the pipeline) is not monadic bind (`>>=`) and will not allow you to "flatten" deeply nested loops like `>>=` does. For alternative approaches to the task that will look better in Elixir you can:

1. Use a library implementing a syntax for Monads (or add your own), like [MonadEx](https://github.com/rob-brown/MonadEx)
2. Stop using this loopy approach and for example generate an assignment of numbers to letters using a recursive function upfront, like so:

   ```
   defmodule Smm do
     # some more things

     def assignments(0, _), do: [[]]
     def assignments(n, digits \\ Enum.into(0..9, HashSet.new)) do
       digits
       |> Stream.flat_map(fn (d) ->
         for rest <- assignments(n - 1, Set.delete(digits, d)) do
           [d | rest]
         end
       end)
     end
   end

   for [s, e, n, d, m, o, r, y] <- Smm.assignments(8) do
     w_send = Smm.to_number([s, e, n, d])
     w_more = Smm.to_number([m, o, r, e])
     w_money = Smm.to_number([m, o, n, e, y])

     if s > 0 && m > 0 && (w_send + w_more == w_money) do
       IO.inspect([w_send, w_more, w_money])
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks to you both! Both answers are very helpful and equally useful in their own ways. I find it difficult to choose a "correct" answer.

Answer (score 3):

This syntactic distraction is eliminated in Haskell by two things: operator associativity and a nice language rule for lambdas.

Having [associativity rules](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html#operator-table) eliminates unnecessary parenthesis in syntax. For example, in Elixir addition associates to the left, so when you write `a + 2 + x` it's interpreted as `(a + 2) + x`. The associativity rule let you get rid of parenthesis. If instead you meant `a + (2 + x)` you would have to write that explicitly.

You can get the operator associativity to help out in Elixir, and some people already have. The [MonadEx](https://github.com/rob-brown/MonadEx) library defines a bind operator `~>>` that would let you write the guts of the program approximately as

```
    Smm.remove(digits, [0])
    ~>> fn s -> Smm.remove(digits, [s])
    ~>> fn e -> Smm.remove(digits, [s,e])
    ~>> fn n -> Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n])
    ~>> fn d -> return(Smm.to_number([s,e,n,d]))
    ~>> fn w_send -> Smm.remove(digits, [0,s,e,n,d])
    ~>> fn m -> Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m])
    ~>> fn o -> Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m,o])
    ~>> fn r -> return(Smm.to_number([m,o,r,e]))
    ~>> fn w_more -> Smm.remove(digits, [s,e,n,d,m,o,r])
    ~>> fn y -> return(Smm.to_number([m,o,n,e,y]))
    ~>> fn w_money -> Smm.guard(w_send + w_more == w_money)
    ~>> fn -> return([w_send, w_more, w_money])
    end end end end end end end end end end end end
```

Operator associativity doesn't get rid of the lambda expressions all ending in the same place. The later expressions need to be inside the earlier lambdas so they can see the variables introduced earlier. Haskell gets rid of this distraction by a simple syntax rule ["lambda abstractions ... extend as far to the right as possible"](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html). Because lambdas extend all the way to the right, Haskell code written in the same style doesn't have a whole bunch of end parenthesis.

```
solutions = remove [0] digits >>= \s ->
            remove [s] digits >>= \e ->
            remove [s,e] digits >>= \n ->
            remove [s,e,n] digits >>= \d ->
            let send = to_number [s,e,n,d]
            in remove [0,s,e,n,d] digits >>= \m ->
            remove [s,e,n,d,m] digits >>= \o ->
            remove [s,e,n,d,m,o] digits >>= \r ->
            let more = to_number [m,o,r,e]
            in remove [s,e,n,d,m,o,r] digits >>= \y ->
            let money = to_number [m,o,n,e,y] in
            guard (send + more == money) >>= \_ ->
            return (send, more, money)
```

I can't imagine a corresponding trick for Elixir. Every `fn` has to `end` at the end, so there will be as many `end`s as there were binds. I guess you'll just need to keep flipping tables `(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻`.

Comment: Thanks to you both! Both answers are very helpful and equally useful in their own ways. I find it difficult to choose a "correct" answer.